# Uppercase and lowercase mapping of GUID in Glass.Mapper

Tags: .net, solr, sitecore6, glass-mapper

what determines on how GUID are mapped from sitecore using Glass.Mapper: uppercase vs lowercase?

Now I see it's lowercase but I can bet I had in the past uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Guid` is lowercase and `Sitecore.Data.ID` is uppercase. The two are interchangeable. `new ID(Guid id)` vs `sitecoreId.Guid`. This can be particularly important when working with indexes, as Sitecore ID's are typically stored as lowercase without braces and hyphens in the index. So in n index queries, you can use `mySitecoreID.Guid.ToString('N')`